# taglib-ruby how to add and edit tags via active storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, taglib, id3, taglib-ruby

I am trying to build an application where I can upload mp3s and pull the current meta data info and change it and write to it if need be. Taking it one step at a time how do I simply read the meta data in when a song is created?

The song model has_many_attached :files

The files upload to the public/uploads directory. I'm at a loss at this point in hwo to do the rest with taglib-ruby.

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense to use an API for your application, and you'll have less effort.